# How to load multiple list view inside single list view?

Tags: json, listview, flutter, scrollview

I'm working on flutter app in which I want to show feeds, I want to show 1st list(Horizontal list) with 4 workouts, 2nd list (Vertical list) with 4 posts, 3rd list (Horizontal list) with 4 coaches and 4th list again 4 posts. At the end of list there is 'Load More' button and after click on button again repeating 1st step i.e. 4 workouts, 4 Posts, 4 Coaches and 4 Posts. My question is What is the best way to display this type of view.

[Video For clear my points](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ageru-f4fc9.appspot.com/o/PostImages%2FszVywTuDZTgEHkQGS2b9CNKzXg33%2FQuestion%2FScreen%20Recording%202019-10-10%20at%2012.51.18%20PM.mov?alt=media&token=460736de-7281-4c37-b028-5cc519377f80)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for  [SliverList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want to achieve:

```
List<List<String>> lists = [["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"],["B1","B2","B3"],["C1","C2","C3","C4","C5"],["D1","D2","D3"]];

Widget buildCard(String text) {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
    child: Text(text),
  );
}

Widget buildHorizontalList(List<String> sublist) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 200.0,
    child: ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: sublist.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildCard("${sublist[index]}"),
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildVerticalList(List<String> sublist) {
  return ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: sublist.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return buildCard("${sublist[index]}");
    },
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: lists.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index <= lists.length - 1) {
            return index.isEven ? buildHorizontalList(lists[index]) : buildVerticalList(lists[index]);
          }
          return RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Load More'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                lists.addAll([["X1","X2","X3","X4","X5"],["Y1","Y2","Y3"]]);
              });
            },
          );
        }),
  );
}
```

**Edit:** I added the Load More button functionality, basically the button just update the 'lists' variable (a list that contains all the sublists). Then the ListViews are being build according to the 'lists' content.

Comment: Thanks Pablo Barrera, Can you please also clear how to 'Load More' works?

Comment: Thanks again Pablo Barrera, This answer save my days.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you, instead of showing every `listview` within another `listview`, just show it all within a `SingleChildScrollView`, and then just add all the `listviews` to a `row` widget.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
      children<widget>[
         // Put listviews here.
      ],
   ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks #Thor, Can you please also clear how to 'Load More' works?

Comment: If I understand you correct, you want a button underneath all of your lists? For this I would just put the button underneath the lists within the children<widget> in the column.